# How to overwrite .php file of lib directory?

Tags: magento2.3, json

Any one tell me how i can overwrite this file in magento 2.3

Path:

> Magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Response\Renderer\Json.php

Comment: which method you want to override?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Create **di.xml** under app/code/vendor/Module/etc and put below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="\Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Response\Renderer\Json" type="Vendor\Module\Webapi\Rest\Response\Renderer\Json" />
</config>
```

Comment: Hi Ansar, in magento 2.3 folder structure are differ we can not crate any new folder/file directly in vendor so can you please suggest solution for Magento 2.3 version?

Comment: you have no need to create directory in vendor , you need to create a custom module in app/code directory i just give temp name of module  Vendor\Module you need to put your name on that

Comment: I try this as well find below my code:                                                                
 di.xml                                                                                                                    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Response\Renderer" type="Evolve\Apirenderer\Webapi\Rest\Response\Renderer" />

</config>    but not working!

Comment: can you use this xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd" instead of  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd"

Comment: Not Working :                                                                                                                            <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Response\Renderer" type="Evolve\Apirenderer\Webapi\Rest\Response\Renderer" />
</config>

Comment: can you paste here what changes you are doing on the Renderer.php file

Comment: I am doing changes in json.php file which is located at Magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Response\Renderer\Json.php in this function "render()" , "return json_encode(array('data'=>array_values($data)));" instead of this "return $this->encoder->encode($data);

Comment: Then you did not put whole class name  <preference for="\Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Response\Renderer\Json" type="Vendor\Module\Webapi\Rest\Response\Renderer\Json" />

Comment: Yes it's working........

Comment: yes remove .php from Json.php just use this Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Response\Renderer\Json only

Answer (score 0):

Find below the code which is working just need to put file name no need of extension of file.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Response\Renderer\Json" type="Evolve\Apirenderer\Webapi\Rest\Response\Renderer\Json" />
</config>

Answer (score 0):

Follow Below Steps:

1. **Overwrite this file**:

   > \Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Response\Renderer\Json.php
2. **We are overwrite Json.php file using** : di.xml (under app/code/Bhashkar/Module/etc and put below code)

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="\Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Response\Renderer\Json" type="Bhashkar\Module\Webapi\Rest\Response\Renderer\Json" />
</config>
```

3. **Create Bhashkar\Webapi\Webapi\Rest\Response\Renderer\Json.php File and modify the functionality as per your Requirement** :

   namespace Bhashkar\Module\Webapi\Rest\Response\Renderer;

   ```
   class Json implements \Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Response\RendererInterface
   {
       /**
        * Adapter mime type.
        */
       const MIME_TYPE = 'application/json';

       /**
        * @var \Magento\Framework\Json\Encoder
        */
       protected $encoder;

       /**
        * Initialize dependencies.
        *
        * @param \Magento\Framework\Json\Encoder $encoder
        */
       public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\Json\Encoder $encoder)
       {
           $this->encoder= $encoder;
       }

       /**
        * Convert data to JSON.
        *
        * @param object|array|int|string|bool|float|null $data
        * @return string
        */
       public function render($data)
       {
           return $this->encoder->encode($data);
       }

       /**
        * Get JSON renderer MIME type.
        *
        * @return string
        */
       public function getMimeType()
       {
           return self::MIME_TYPE;
       }
   }
   ```